# How can I have my slack app listen and respond to event across different workspaces?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

So I am using `Bot User OAuth Token` for initialising my slack App, and listening to message like this

```js
slackApp.message(
  "hey",
  async ({ body, context, message, client, event, say }) => {
    try {
      say({
        channel: event.channel,
        token: botToken,
        text: "Hola!",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("err");
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
);
```

The issue is, I have this app installed in two workspace
Workspace A -> I am part of this workspace, from where I created this app initially
Workspace B -> Another user installed in this workspace

Now if a user sends `hey` into app message in workspace A, it is able to respond, but if a user sends `hey` in workspace B, event is captured, but `say()` doesn't work, because of this error `channel_not_found`. I guess because this token only corresponds to Workspace A?
How should I make it to listen and respond to all workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

When the app was installed to Workspace B your app should've been granted a bot token corresponding to that installation. That comes as a response to `[oauth.v2.access][1]` during the OAuth flow. You're meant to store those tokens so if you haven't you might need to uninstall the app from Workspace B and have the user go through the Oauth flow again.

Comment: Yes token is returned, but am I supposed to listen to each workspace events?

Comment: My use case is listen and respond to this ‘hey’ message for all the workspace with say

Comment: If you've verified that you are using the right tokens ( the token corresponding to each workspace) then the next thing to address would be the `channe_not_found` error. This could mean that your bot is not in the channel, maybe the channel is private?